# onsubmit close popup which is inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Here is form code

```
  <form method="POST" action="https://totemworldwide.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_3_"  onsubmit="closePopup()">
```

and here is jquery popup close code

```
function closePopup(){
  setTimeout($('#cboxClose').trigger('click'), 2000 ); 
}
```

Here is live website in case you want to test 
http://www.totemworldwide.com/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @ceejayoz  yes i understand same origion policy but i only need help to close popup and i believe we can trigger click event to close pop-up..

Comment: `www.totemworldwide.com` and `totemworldwide.activehosted.com` are separate origins. One will not be able to affect the other via JS without the right CORS setup.

Comment: oh, sorry for confusion , actually i'm submitting this optin form to active campaign and it is working without any issue.  i'm using super-pop wordpress plugin to show optin form in popup..    when form is submitted i want to close popup.   hope this make sense.